# Typing Errors in TypeScript for @types/node/ts4.8/test.d.ts:876-921

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules, angular-devkit

I'm encountering an issue with my TypeScript. I have an Angular 11 application, and when attempting to compile the code, I'm receiving a series of error messages referring to node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/test.d.ts. Here are some of the error messages:

Error: node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/test.d.ts:876:25 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'abstract'.
...
Error: node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/test.d.ts:921:31 - error TS2707: Generic type 'MockFunctionCall<F, ReturnType, unknown, Args>' requires between 3 and 4 type arguments.

I think I need to upgrade my typescipt version but i can not do that because of a dependency to:
@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.19".(I need to upgrade to angular 12 if I want to upgrade this)

My Configuration:

TypeScript: 4.1.6
Angular: 11
@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.19"
"webpack": "^5.0.0",

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIhVu.png) when i Do  npm ls @types/node

Questions:

How can I resolve these errors without having to upgrade my TypeScript version?

I tried to upgrade my typescript version but got dependency issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular 11 doesn't [not support](https://angular.io/guide/versions) Typscript 4.8

Depending on you exact version here is the TS compatibility range :

```
angular       typescript
11.2.x :    >=4.0.0 <4.2.0  
11.1.x :    >=4.0.0 <4.2.0
11.0.x :    ~4.0.0
```

Comment: I have:
"@angular/core": "~11.2.14",
"typescript": "^4.0.2",

and got a lot of errors, after uppgrading to angular 11:

Error: node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/test.d.ts:904:63 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

904         target: F extends abstract new(...args: any) => any ? F : undefined;
                                                                  ~


Error: node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/test.d.ts:904:76 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

904         target: F extends abstract new(...args: any) => any ? F : undefined;

Comment: can you do `npm ls @types/node` ?

Comment: Yes, I added a picture in my question!

Comment: I solved it when I downgrade @types/node.